# Creating table in php using PEAR

Tags: php, pear

I've been trying to create tables using the PEAR package,my table look like this:

```
 <?php include_once 'HTML/Table.php';

    $mytable = new HTML_Table();
    $mytable->setAutoGrow(true);


    $p1 = array('0'=>"<a href='index.php'><img src='img/appicons/hme.png' /></a><p id='imgdes'>Home</p>",
        '1'=>"<a href='loginadmin.php'><img src='img/userlogin.png' /></a><p id='imgdes'>Admin Login</p>",
        '2'=>"<a href='loginuser.php'><img src='img/appicons/login_icon.png' /></a><p id='imgdes'>Member Login</p>",
        '3'=>"<a href='about.php'><img src='img/appicons/abtus.png' /></a><p id='imgdes'>About Us</p>",
        '4'=>"<a href='enquiry.php'><img src='img/appicons/contact.png' /></a><p id='imgdes'>Enquiries</p>"
        );

    $mytable->setAutoFill('');
    $mytable->setCellContents(0, 0,$p1[0]);
    $mytable->setCellContents(0, 1,$p1[1]);
    $mytable->setCellContents(1, 0, $p1[2]);
    $mytable->setCellContents(1, 1, $p1[3]);
    $mytable->setCellContents(2, 0, $p1[4]);

    echo $mytable->toHtml();
?>
```

The content of my table is usually displayed after some of these annoying messages:

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\HTML\Table.php on line 667

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\HTML\Table\Storage.php on line 413.

Please can someone help me to fix this or give me suggestion(s) on how to go about it? Thanks

Comment: I one wrote an amazing library that wrote one character to the screen, it looked something like $TheCharacter=new Character(); $TheCharacter->set('utf8');$theCharacter->ascii('118');$theCharacter->render(); Today, I realized it would be simpler to echo 'v';

Answer (score 1):

Those warnings are because HTML_Table is not E_STRICT-compatible. The code still works, though.

The only way to circumvent that is by disabling E_STRICT errors:

```
error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_STRICT);
```